# Retrieving information and sending it to an input box cakePHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have an e-mail form which is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('To');
echo $this->Form->input('Subject');
echo $this->Form->input('Message');
```

Below the form I have a list of user names:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($users as $user):
    $class = null;
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
        $class = ' class="altrow"';}?>

<tr<?php echo $class;?>>
    <td><?php echo $user['User']['name'].'   '.$user['User']['surname']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

All I want to do is to get the an e-mail address of a user to be listed in the e-mail form's 'To: ' field once a user has clicked on any name in the list.

Comment: This is not a question about CakePHP, I would recommend you to add other tags such as jQuery or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the selector function:

```
$('tr').click(function ()
    $('input[id="To"]').text($(this).text());
}
```

Comment: altrow is only for every second row. he would need use tr in general or add some specific class here. also, "To" will most likely be not the id. More like "ModelnameTo". But other than that spot on!